# Color ListView item using alert dialog android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to color the item in the listview. When I clicked the item in listview the alert dialog shows then it colors the item if your click yes in the dialog using setChoiceMode multiple, The problem is whenever I click the item before the alert dialog shows the listview item already colored, Please check this out, I'm just a newbie in android thank you.

[image]

> MainActivity.java

```
 text_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            isSelected[position]=!isSelected[position];
            alert_dialog();

        }
    });
}
public void alert_dialog(){
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Are you sure you want to color this item?")
            .setMessage("Please Confirm")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    text_listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing Happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

> myselecter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/lightOrange" android:state_activated="true"/> 
</selector>
```

> arrayadapter

```
    ArrayList<String> list_items = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private boolean[] isSelected;  //declaration

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, list_items);
    text_listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    isSelected=new boolean[arrayAdapter.getCount()];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to set the selection after clicking on yes in dailog. Modify your code like this.

```
text_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            alert_dialog(position);

        }
    });
}

public void alert_dialog(final int position){
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Are you sure you want to color this item?")
            .setMessage("Please Confirm")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                     isSelected[position]=true;
                     text_listview.setItemChecked(position,true); //Setting selected state here 
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                      isSelected[position]=false;
                      text_listview.setItemChecked(position,false); 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing Happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

Comment: Hey its you again, I setting my choice mode multiple to my mainactivity to highlight the item , but it seems that you remove the choice mode multiple to your example and it didn't highlight the listview, how to do it? thanks  @PraveenSP

Comment: No you have mentioned multiple choice mode to listview right in xml itself ...

Comment: The function works well it works but why is the item highlighted when I clicked before the dialog shows?same on the image above I think there is missing on my code @PraveenSP

Comment: Why it always highlighted when clicking It has already condition in dialog, Still don't know what to do @PraveenSp